# Evitar modificación de parámetros (por inspector de navegador)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

me encuentro en la inquietud de saber si existe alguna manera o técnica específica para evitar la modificacion de codigo por el inspector del navegador.

```
<button class="dltBtn" data-id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</button>
```

```
<button class="dltBtn" onclick='editar(1)' href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</button>
```

Esos dos ejemplos de código son faciles de editar por navegador.

Necesito ayuda para incrementar la seguridad de mi sistema, ya sea por el lado del cliente o del servidor.

Comment: En el navegador todo se puede modificar y no hay alguna acción viable para impedirlo, por lo que tienes que hacer todas las validaciones necesarias en el lado del servidor.

Comment: Entiendo pero ponele que quiero eliminar un registro.. o "taguearlo" como eliminado... que verificacion puedo hacer?? si el usuario cambia el id "1" por "500"...

Comment: A grandes rasgos: verificar sesión del usuario. Después, que tenga permisos adecuados para borrar (admin, moderador, etc.), que el registro existe, que pertenece al usuario.

Comment: De momento son verificaciones que hago, Gracias por las respuestas!